# H2OServerError: HTTP 500 Server Error: While training automl

Tags: machine-learning, h2o, automl

I receive following error while training an auto ml model from h2o.

```
H2OServerError: HTTP 500 Server Error:
Server error java.lang.NullPointerException:
Error: Caught exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Request: None
```

This is how I initialized h2o: `h2o.init(nthreads = -1)`
And this is what I received after h2o initialization:

```
Checking whether there is an H2O instance running at http://localhost:54321 . connected.
H2O_cluster_uptime: 31 mins 51 secs
H2O_cluster_timezone:   Asia/Kolkata
H2O_data_parsing_timezone:  UTC
H2O_cluster_version:    3.34.0.1
H2O_cluster_version_age:    3 days
H2O_cluster_name:   H2O_from_python_rosha_vhyf5v
H2O_cluster_total_nodes:    1
H2O_cluster_free_memory:    2.959 Gb
H2O_cluster_total_cores:    4
H2O_cluster_allowed_cores:  4
H2O_cluster_status: locked, healthy
H2O_connection_url: http://localhost:54321
H2O_connection_proxy:   {"http": null, "https": null}
H2O_internal_security:  False
H2O_API_Extensions: Amazon S3, Algos, AutoML, Core V3, TargetEncoder, Core V4
Python_version: 3.8.8 final
```

And this is how I'm training automl model:

```
aml = H2OAutoML(max_models = 10, max_runtime_secs = 500, stopping_rounds = 5)
aml.train(x = aml_x, y = aml_y, training_frame = train)
```

I exported and processed data as pandas data frame. So, I changed it using

```
train = h2o.H2OFrame(df)
```

I tried the solutions on stack overflow which tries to find error in data by splitting it various halves. I get same error no matter how I split.
And solution asssumes the error pop ups instantly after running the code but in my case it takes about 4-5 second before giving a error.

Please note I have a large dataset of about 200,000 columns and 20 rows.

Comment: I assume you mean 200k rows and 20 columns? The reverse would not be enough rows. Your available memory (2.959 Gb) seems pretty low. Have you tried bumping it up? So if you try a much smaller dataset, it still errors? Can this happen on a dummy dataset? Can you share a reproducible example for others to test and investigate?

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that I got the same error on version 3.34.0.1 when attempting to run automl on a regression problem. Building a GBM didn't throw an error. I downgraded versions to 3.32.1.7 and when running the identical code did not get an error message. For now I would suggest reverting to the prior version until an update is released.